# Schrodinger operator with matrix potential

Tags: harmonic-analysis, operator-theory, elliptic-pde, matrix-theory, schrodinger-operators

This question is inspired by attempts to extend in some way Shen's 1999 "On fundamental solutions of generalized Schrödinger operators" to Schrödinger operators $- \Delta + V  $ with some matrix potential $V : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{M}^{n \times n}$ that is symmetric and positive definite a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Suppose we have some matrix function $M : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{M}^{n \times n}$ that is symmetric and positive definite a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (intuitively, some sort of "Agmon function" on $\mathbb{R}^d$ related to our matrix potential). If we are lucky and have $n = d$ then $M$ canonically induces a metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Namely, just define \begin{equation} d(x, y) =  \inf_\gamma \int_0^1 \langle M(\gamma(t)) \gamma '(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle_{ \mathbb{R}^d} ^\frac12 \, dt \tag{1}\label{Metric}\end{equation} where the infimum is over all absolutely continuous curves $\gamma : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ where $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$.

If $n \neq d$ then there seems no natural way to do this while "preserving" the matrix structure of $M$.  That is, I don't want to look at something like $$d(x, y) =  \inf_\gamma \int_0^1 \|M(\gamma(t))\| |\gamma '(t)|_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \, dt. $$

Surely $M$ can induce a bundle metric on some rank $n$ vector bundle, but it seems impossible to do this canonically in a way that reduces to \eqref{Metric} when $n = d$.

Are there any papers in the Schrödinger operator literature that touch on this?  I can't imagine an issue like this hasn't come up somewhere before.

Comment: Is the Schrodinger operator only for motivational purposes? It looks to me as though your question is just about geometry, and I don't see why you tagged elliptic-pde, and I don't see why you are looking for papers in the Schrodinger operator literature. Should the metric have something to do with the Schrodinger operator in some way?

Comment: Really it's just for motivational purposes (and is also my general reason for asking, as that's what I'm researching right now). Also I find it hard to imagine this situation has't appeared in the theory of Schrodinger operators. I tagged it elliptic-pde because you can ask the same question for more general elliptic operators with a matrix potential and again it's hard to imagine such an issue has never came up in that context (at least to a non-expert like myself. I mostly do classical harmonic analysis).

Though, maybe this also has appeared naturally in other contexts too...

Comment: But what is this metric supposed to tell you about the original Schrodinger operator? Why does it make sense to start from a matrix potential and ask about this metric?

Comment: To answer your other question, I'm essentially assuming apriori that a "useful" matrix valued Agmon function can be defined (analogous to how it is in Zhongwei Shen's 1999  "On fundamental solutions of generalized Schrodinger operators"),  but this is naturally n times n valued, and thus doesn't naturally define an Agmon metric on $\mathbb{R}^d$... Here, it depends on the potential.  What exactly this "Agmon function" is, is still work in progress.

Comment: I want upper and lower exponential decay estimates for the fundamental solutions of such matrix potential Schrodinger operators.  Usually this is in terms of the Agmon metric.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the above ^^ two comments. They provide important context.

Comment: What does "a.e." mean in the first sentence? "almost everywhere" doesn't seem to match. I also don't understand "*defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$*", is something repeated by error?

Comment: That said, why do you think that for the matrix schrodinger operator the "Agmon function" would end up being an $n\times n$ matrix? Whatever definition you guess it should reduce to the standard form when $n = 1$, no?

Comment: @YCor: Concerning the last part of your comment: I think the sentence is to be understood as "a matrix-valued function $M: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ that acts on vector-valued functions $u: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by means of $u \mapsto Mu$.

Comment: @JoshuaIsralowitz: I would be interested in what kind of lower decay estimates you hope for: the lower estimates in Shen's 1999 paper imply, in particular, positivity of the fundamental solution - which is not true for Schrödinger systems that are coupled by matrix-valued potentials (unless the potential satisfies very specific properties).

Comment: @WillieWong Edit made.  And to answer your question, it's not clear what exactly would constitute an appropriate "Agmon function", but thinking about this for a while, I think any kind of scalar function would throw away too much of the matrix structure of $V$.  This is just a hunch.

Comment: @JochenGlueck We (Blair Davey and I)  are imposing some kind of matrix "reverse Holder" condition, or if that's not enough, an additional "matrix A${}_\infty$ condition (something akin to that in Dall'Ara's 2015 paper "Discreteness of the spectrum of Schrodinger operators with non-negative matrix-valued potentials").  What exactly a lower bound would look like, if even possible, is unclear at the moment.

Comment: @JoshuaIsralowitz: I see, thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @JochenGlueck Sure! So far, our efforts have been devoted to proving an appropriate "matrix Poincare inequality" akin to Shen's in his 1999 paper.  This has been more or less successful (and is very much akin to the "matrix weighted Poincare inequality" in my IUMJ paper "Matrix weighted Poincare inequalities..." with Kabe Moen).  Now we are seeing what's possible with this "Poincare inequality".

Comment: What is an "Agmon function", for those not in the know?

Comment: @Igor Khavkine, this probably isn't the standard interpretation of an "Agmon function" (and I'm  using the word "a" instead of "the" intentionally), but the way I interpret it is (and this is important for our project):

To prove upper/lower decay estimates in Shen's paper, a key step is what's called a Fefferman-Phong inequality, which practically speaking is a global weighted Poincare inequality (specifically for weights, aka scalar positive potentials, in certain reverse Holder classes, which is just for technical reasons).

Comment: What Shen then does, is apply this local Poincare inequality on Euclidean balls B(x, r(x)) where the radius r(x) is judiciously picked, multiply both sides by a "local to global correction factor" (i.e. an Agmon function), and integrate both sides with respect to x, to get the Fefferman-Phong inequality.  Any "correction factor" satisfying certain properties works.  

Again this is might not be standard thinking, but this is how I interpret the situation.